# Calculating the gradient of residual sum of squares via product rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, matrix-calculus

I know that
$\nabla_{\textbf{w}}\text{RSS}(\textbf{w})=\nabla((y-\text{H}\textbf{w})^{T}(y-\text{H}\textbf{w}))=-2\text{H}^{T}(y-\text{H}\textbf{w})$. However, I am having trouble deriving this via the product rule. (I know there are other ways to do this but I am particularly interested in this method)

Here is what I have so far

$$\nabla((y-\text{H}\textbf{w})^{T}(y-\text{H}\textbf{w}))\\
=\nabla((y^{T}-\textbf{w}^T\text{H}^T)(y-\text{H}\textbf{w})) \\
=(-\text{H})(y-\text{H}\textbf{w}) +(y^{T}-\textbf{w}^T\text{H}^T)(-\text{H}) \\
=(-\text{H})(y-\text{H}\textbf{w}) +(y-\text{H}\textbf{w})^{T}(-\text{H})
$$

This is not equal to the proven gradient, nor is it even defined. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: what is the product rule?

Comment: The gradient can be represented either as a column vector or a row vector. For the two addends in your last line, the first one is a column vector and the second one is a row vector. Transposing the row vector into a column vector will fix the problem.

Comment: In general, take care when symbolically calculating gradients to make sure dimensions match and make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multivariate gradient can be confusing, especially regarding when we should transpose the vector(s). If you have just started learning, I recommend to check using the indices notation:

$$
RSS=
\left(
y_{i}-H_{ip}w_{p}
\right)
\left(
y_{i}-H_{iq}w_{q}
\right)
$$

Here we use the Einstein notation: when two matching indices are present in a product, it means sum of products over all possible values of that index. Now the gradient:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\nabla RSS\right)_{j}
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{j}}RSS
\\
&=
-H_{ij}\left(y_{i}-H_{iq}w_{q}\right)-
\left(y_{i}-H_{ip}w_{p}\right)H_{ij}
\\
&=
-2H_{ij}\left(y_{i}-H_{ip}w_{p}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we convert it back to matrix - vector notation:

$$
\nabla RSS=-2\mathbf{H}^{\top}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{H}\mathbf{w}\right)
$$

So your mistake is in the second term of LHS on the second row, you should transpose that term and you will get the correct expression.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the product rule, it is a quadratic and the gradient can be computed directly.

Let $f(w) = (y-Hw)^T (y-Hw)$, then
$f(w+h) = f(w) + (-2H^T (y-Hw))^T h + h^T H^T H h$ from which it follows that $\nabla f(w) = -2H^T (y-Hw)$.